# How did TestNg annotation mentioned in one class get executed from another from another class?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

While learning Testng on Udemy, I come across a code which I am unable to understand. Instructor has created class named "testcore" where he defined @BeforeMethod/@aftermethod.Later he created another class named "LoginTest" where he wrote actual test with @test. He extended testcore class in loginTest to get variable initiated in testcore class. When he ran loginTest then @BeforeMethod/@aftermethod also ran with this. **How did these two method ran along with @test when these methods are in different class.**
here are both codes:

```
    public class testcore {

    public  static Properties config = new Properties();
    public  static Properties obj = new Properties();
    public  static Xls_Reader  xls = null;
    public static WebDriver driver;//=null;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void init()  throws Exception{

        if(driver==null) {

        // Loading Config Properties File
        File Config_f = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\dd_Properties\\config.properties");
        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(Config_f);
        config.load(fs);

        // Loading Object Properties File
        File Obj_f = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\dd_Properties\\Object.properties");
        fs = new FileInputStream(Obj_f);
        obj.load(fs);

        //Loading xlsx file
        xls = new Xls_Reader(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\dd_Properties\\Data.xlsx");

        System.out.println(config.getProperty("browerName"));

        if(config.getProperty("browerName").equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox")) {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();   
        }
        else if(config.getProperty("browerName").equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome")) {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception("Wrong/No Browswer sepcified");
        }

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }


}
    @AfterMethod
    public void quitdriver() throws EmailException {
        driver.quit();

        //monitoringMail.Sendmail();
    }
```

Here are LoginTest class:

```
public class LoginTest extends testcore {


@Test
public void doLogin() {

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(obj.getProperty("LoginBtn"))).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(obj.getProperty("username"))).sendKeys();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(obj.getProperty("password"))).sendKeys();


}
```

Comment: Explained in the official documentation for this - http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#methods

Comment: Thanks ffor reply. But I did not find any suitable content in doc to clarify my doubt. Please help to point out that content in doc.

Comment: It is a simple Java Inheritance Concept. Since, the class `LoginTest` extends the class `testcore`, both the `BeforeMethod` and `AfterMethod` are available to the `LoginTest` class. So, when you run `Test` method, `BeforeMethod` and `AfterMethod` also gets executed. Hope this helps.

Comment: If there were other methods not annotated with beforemethod and aftermethod, will it still be executed automatically if I do not use object to access those methods ? If not then why? @shank087

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) How did these two method ran along with @test.

First of all  *LoginTest* **extends** the *testcore* .

Due to this we can inherit the method of testcore in our LoginTest class.

2) When he ran loginTest then @BeforeMethod/@aftermethod also ran with this.

Please refer below details

Configuration information for a TestNG class:

```
@BeforeSuite: The annotated method will be run before all tests in this suite have run. 
@AfterSuite: The annotated method will be run after all tests in this suite have run. 
@BeforeTest: The annotated method will be run before any test method belonging to the classes inside the <test> tag is run. 
@AfterTest: The annotated method will be run after all the test methods belonging to the classes inside the <test> tag have run. 
@BeforeGroups: The list of groups that this configuration method will run before. This method is guaranteed to run shortly before the first test method that belongs to any of these groups is invoked. 
@AfterGroups: The list of groups that this configuration method will run after. This method is guaranteed to run shortly after the last test method that belongs to any of these groups is invoked. 
@BeforeClass: The annotated method will be run before the first test method in the current class is invoked. 
@AfterClass: The annotated method will be run after all the test methods in the current class have been run. 
@BeforeMethod: The annotated method will be run before each test method. 
@AfterMethod: The annotated method will be run after each test method.
```

Comment: Thanks for reply ankur. But I am looking different answer... I have ran LoginTest directly( Right click+run ), not through xml. Then how did LoginTest run took @beforeMethod from Testcore class?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yes, `LoginTest` class is extending the `testcore` class and obviously when you run the `LoginTest` class, it will execute the before and after methods as well. Hope this helps and you can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple inheritance related question. When you have extended testcore class in LoginTest class all the methods and data member available in parent will be available to child class including methods annotated with @Before Method etc.

I think you are confused due to miss concept regarding the way TestNG run a program. There are different different way to run a testNG annotated program to get executed and among them XML is a way. So don't get get confuse that all class, methods need to include in that xml. You just need an entry point only and rest will call accordingly.